# Compile MATLAB function into something that can be run on a linux terminal w.out MATLAB?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, terminal

I have some MATLAB functions that I created on a windows environment. I am not so familiar with C/C++, but I know that it is possible to compile MATLAB into C/C++. I am wondering if there is any way to use the compiled C/C++ and run it as a command on a linux terminal that does not have MATLAB installed? Is there any built in MATLAB functionality for something like this?

For example,

If I have a function that takes as input two numbers, and then returns the sum of those two numbers; can I compile such a MATLAB function, transfer the compiled files to a linux environment, and then run a command such as: function -a -b that would run my MATLAB function on the two numbers a & b.

Comment: There is the Matlab Compiler, which generates binary executables from Matlab code, without an intermediate C/C++ step though. http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/

Comment: Can you run an exe directly on Linux though?

Comment: A linux executable,Yes, but you need to install the MCR(Matlab Compiler Runtime) for the application to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

- Use [MATLAB coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-coder/description1.html), which generates C code from the MATLAB code. You could then compile the C code on linux using gcc.
- Use [MATLAB compiler](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/), which converts the MATLAB code into an executable format. However, I am not sure whether you can use a windows version of MATLAB to create a Linux executable, or whether you need a Unix version of MATLAB to do this. In any case, you will need to install the MATLAB runtime on the target machine, which is large and unwieldy. There is a brief tutorial [here](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/matlab/MatlabCompilerLinux.pdf).